# Python arcpy panToExtent inside of cursor causes Polygon object attribute error

Tags: python, arcpy

Using python 2.7

I have a polygon feature class with multiple rows that I am iterating through with an update cursor. I am creating custom dataframes based on each row (works) but when I try to get each polygon to zoom to the extent of the custom dataframe I keep getting attribute errors. I have also seen many posts using similar functions on SO within cursors so I think it should work, but I cannot get past this error.

I have tried using syntax I got directly from esri page and got an
Attribute error: 'List' object has no attribute 'panToExtent'. (This makes sense since I think the cursor is making a list object).

Then I tried making it a polygon object and now get Attribute error: Polygon obj has no attr 'panToExtent'.

Could this be due to the update cursor? Do I have to convert this somehow?

```
def get_info():
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(testdata,"SHAPE@") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:

        df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
        df.rotation = 0
        df.scale = 63360

        df.elementWidth = curr_width + 10
        df.elementHeight = curr_height + 10

        df_w = df.elementWidth
        df_h = df.elementHeight
        print(df_w, df_h)#YES
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
        cursor.updateRow(row)

        newdf = df

        newdf.extent = newdf.panToExtent(row.getSelectedExtent())#List obj has no attr panToExtent

        newdf.extent = newdf.panToExtent(row[0].getSelectedExtent())#Polygon obj has no attr panToExtent
```

Answer (score 0):

Questions about ArcGIS products are going to get much better visibility over at [Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/).  Regardless of what Stack site you post on, you need to post complete, self-contained code. The code posted here references variables that are outside the scope of what is posted, so it makes community members guess or assume information, which is never a good thing.

Since I don't know if you will delete this question and re-post a *complete* question on GIS SE, I will make a couple assumptions and reply here.  A few general comments on code structure before diving into the specifics ArcPy DataFrame.

- Only instantiate an object within a loop if it needs to be; otherwise, you are incurring overhead to recreate the same object over and over for no reason.
- Only use an update cursor if you need to update records; otherwise, use a search cursor.  Update cursors will add additional locks to the geodatabase and tables that aren't needed if you aren't updating data.  *I am pointing this out because your `cursor.updateRow(row)` line is accomplishing nothing since you are passing the row back without making any changes to its contents*
- I am not sure what the point of `newdf = df` is since you are not creating a new dataframe but simply a second reference to the first dataframe.

Moving onto the heart of the problem....  The error message for your last line states, `Attribute error: Polygon obj has no attr 'panToExtent'`.  If you look at Esri's documentation for [Polygon -- ArcMap | Documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/polygon.htm), you will see that Polygon objects have no method named `panToExtent()`, hence the attribute error stating such.  I suggest spending some more time reading ArcPy documentation because you seem mixed up on the properties and methods of various objects.

Below is some proof-on-concept code for using the extents of geometries in a feature class to change the extent of a dataframe.

```py
import time
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
df.rotation = 0
df.scale = 63360
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("<insert layer name>", "SHAPE@") as cur:
    for row in cur:
        shp = row[0]
        df.panToExtent(shp.extent)
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
        time.sleep(1)  # a sleep call is needed or it will loop over records so fast you won't see any changes, just the last change
```